# EOF error in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell, recursion, fibonacci

I am working on creating a simple script to get the Fibonacci Series using Recursion in shell Scripting.

The program is as follows :

```
#! /bin/bash

# Program to calculate the Fibonacci Series using Recursion

export MidNumber=2

# Define the function
fibonacci()
{
  indx=$1 // Base Case
  if [ "$indx" -lt "$MidNumber ]
  then
   echo "$idnx"
  else
   echo -n "$(( $(fibonacci $(($indx-2)))+$(fibonacci $(($indx-1))) ))"
  fi
 }

read MAXTERM

for (( i=0; i<=$MAXTERM; i++ ))
do
 fibonacci $i
done

echo
```

I am getting the error

```
./FibonacciRecursion.sh: line 15: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./FibonacciRecursion.sh: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Please if someone can help me out. I am new to shell scripting.

Comment: You have a mismatched quote in your `if` line. Syntax highlighting in your editor should have shown you that.

Comment: And, even if your editor doesn't show you the problem, the syntax highlighting on SO shows that there is a double quote missing on `if [ "$indx" -lt "$MidNumber ]` before the `]`, (though the error is reported against the last double quote on the `echo -n` line because that's the last double quote in the script file.  Note that in POSIX-ish shells, strings are not constrained to a single line, unlike in C shells.  I can't help but feel that you could improve the spacing in the line with the recursive calls.  The `-n` also seems to be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the missing `"` and the unhelpful `-n` mentioned in the comments, there's

- line 10: `//` is not a comment delimiter in `bash`; you can use `#`.
- line 13: You mistyped `indx` as `idnx`.